# Blinking cursor on console during cout string

Tags: c++

When the console opens and the program runs I only get a blinking cursor. 
Is there something that I am doing wrong? Is the program running too fast for me to see it?

Thank you for any help in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

string RandomString(int len)
{
    srand(time(0));
    string str = "01213456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int pos;
    while (str.size() != len) {
        pos = ((rand() % (str.size() - 1)));
    }

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    string random_str = RandomString(10);
    cout << "random_str : " << random_str << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `RandomString` function is not adding any characters to `str`. It will never return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your `while` loop never exits:

```
    while (str.size() != len) {
        pos = ((rand() % (str.size() - 1)));
    }
```

You only update `pos` in the loop, but you don't use `pos` in the `while` condition.